# Add all List elements only to the RightNode of a Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have created a Linkedlist and add some elements on it. Now I want to add all the elements from the LinkedList to Tree. Only on the RightNode. Leftnode will be empty. Tree will be just like below--

```
        10
          \
           20
            \
             30
              \
               40
```

I have written the following code. But it's overwritten its's node. Not giving the correct output. My code is given below --

My Binary Tree is --

```
  public class TreeNode {
     int val;
     TreeNode left;
     TreeNode right;
     TreeNode() {}
     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
       this.val = val;
       this.left = left;
       this.right = right;
     }
  }
```

---

```
    Queue<Integer> lst = new LinkedList<>();        
    
    lst.add(10);
    lst.add(20);
    lst.add(30);
    lst.add(40);
    
    TreeNode nRoot=null;
    
    while(!lst.isEmpty()){                      
        
        if(nRoot==null)
            nRoot = new TreeNode(lst.poll());
        else{
            nRoot.right = new TreeNode(lst.poll());                        
            nRoot=nRoot.right;
        }
    }
```

Which is giving the output --

```
    Output - [10]
    Expected Output - [10,null,20,null,30,null,40]
```

---

Please help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the "Parent node" of each node of tree. So you cannot go backward to the root element of tree.

so your code should be like this:

```
public class TreeNode {
 int val;
 TreeNode left;
 TreeNode right;
 TreeNode parent;
 TreeNode() {}
 TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
   this.val = val;
   this.left = left;
   this.right = right;
 }
}
```

and then :

```
while(!lst.isEmpty()){                      
    
    if(nRoot==null)
        nRoot = new TreeNode(lst.poll());
    else{
        nRoot.right = new TreeNode(lst.poll());
        TreeNode parent=nRoot;                        
        nRoot=nRoot.right;
        nRoot.parent=parent;
    }
}
```

now you can do this way to print your tree:

```
while(nRoot!=null){
 system.out.writeln(nRoot.val);
 nRoot=nRoot.parent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Suppose I don't want to change my TreeNode. I dont want to add any extra node for Parent in the TreeNode class. Is there any other way to keep track of the ParetNode. So that I can backword?

Comment: Thanks. I am able to solve the problem. Its. Working now.

Comment: Yes, in the initialize of your tree, when you check if(nRoot==null), that's parent node , just keep that in a temp variable and go forward from it.